# Check if file exist inside tar file using tar and grep command

Tags: unix, ksh, tar

I have a script that check if a file exist inside a tar file but something's wrong because it always go to the 'else' part of the script. I am pretty sure that it shouldn't be that way.

The date is in "Mon dd" format (Jan 11).

```
echo "enter date: \c"
read date
tarfile=`tar -tvf tarfile.tar | grep some_file | grep "$date"`

if [ -f "$tarfile" ]; then
   echo "yes"
else
   echo "no"
fi
```

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was also asked here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97068/tar-and-if-statement and answered, so I'm closing this variant.

Answer (score 10):

Because `some_file` is inside the `tarfile.tar` file but your `if` is checking for it to be on the file system.

You can alter it like this

```
if tar –tf tarfile.tar some_file >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "tarfile.tar contains some_file"
fi
```